# Цикл for проходит один раз PHP

Tags: php, laravel

Всем привет, подскажите пожалуйста почему мой цикл проходит всего один раз..

вот мой код

```html
public function getDateHolidayArr($holidaysEmployee)
    {
        $allDates = array();

        $count = count($holidaysEmployee);

        if ($count == 0)
        {
            return $allDates;
        }

        for ($i = 0; $i <= $count; $i++)
        {
        $holidaysFrom = $holidaysEmployee[$i]->holidays_from;
        $holidaysBefore = $holidaysEmployee[$i]->holidays_before;

        $startDate = new Carbon($holidaysFrom);
        $endDate = new Carbon($holidaysBefore);

            while ($startDate->lte($endDate)) {
                $allDates[] = $startDate->toDateString();

                $startDate->addDay();
            }
           
        return $allDates;

        }

    }
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

когда убираю return с цикла то появляется офсетная ошибка
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

вынес ретурн за цикл но та же офсетная ошибка

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

PS
каунт 2 показывает, первый массив из коллекции перебирается, если ставлю допустим у $i значение 1 то перебирается второй массив.. получается сам цикл тормозится..

Comment: Проверьте переменную $count может она пуста. Он выполняет условие if и выводит return. На этом цикл заканчивается.

Comment: каунт 2 показывает, первый массив из коллекции перебирается, если ставлю допустим у   $i значение 1 то перебирается второй массив.. получается сам цикл тормозится..

Comment: У вас с offset ошибка т.к. цикл вы с 0 начинаете и до <= count, в то время когда count считается с 1. То есть, вы раз проходитесь по не существующему эл-ту. либо сделайте < count, либо c 1 цикл запускайте

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Уберите return с цикла... и все заработает

```
public function getDateHolidayArr($holidaysEmployee)
{
    $allDates = array();

    $count = count($holidaysEmployee);

    if ($count == 0)
    {
        return $allDates;
    }

    for ($i = 0; $i <= $count; $i++)
    {
    $holidaysFrom = $holidaysEmployee[$i]->holidays_from;
    $holidaysBefore = $holidaysEmployee[$i]->holidays_before;

    $startDate = new Carbon($holidaysFrom);
    $endDate = new Carbon($holidaysBefore);

        while ($startDate->lte($endDate)) {
            $allDates[] = $startDate->toDateString();

            $startDate->addDay();
        }


        //return $allDates;
    }
    return $allDates;
}
```

Comment: вынес ретурн за цикл но та же офсетная ошибка

Comment: dd уберите , зачем он там

Comment: ддешкой смотрю чтобы нужный массив был на выходе

Answer (score 0):

Прошу заметить, у вас стоит оператор return в теле цикла ;)
Этот оператор моментально прерывает выполнение тела функции...

---

Вы можете каждую итерацию цикла прибавлять значение к переменной, а затем сделать return.

```php
public function getDateHolidayArr($holidaysEmployee)
{
    $allDates = array();

    $count = count($holidaysEmployee);

    if ($count == 0)
    {
        return $allDates;
    }

    for ($i = 0; $i <= $count; $i++)
    {
    $holidaysFrom = $holidaysEmployee[$i]->holidays_from;
    $holidaysBefore = $holidaysEmployee[$i]->holidays_before;

    $startDate = new Carbon($holidaysFrom);
    $endDate = new Carbon($holidaysBefore);

        while ($startDate->lte($endDate)) {
            $allDates[] = $startDate->toDateString();

            $startDate->addDay();
        }


        //return $allDates;
    }
    return $allDates;
}
```

Comment: без return офсетная ошибка вылетает.. http://i.imgur.com/eogf3Kt.png
http://i.imgur.com/eogf3Kt.png

Comment: можно пример пожалуйста.. а то мозг уже плывет..

Comment: Нельзя убирать return, ведь функции должны возвращать какое-то значение. Попробуйте опустить return ниже предпоследней скобки, но выше последней...

Comment: вынес ретурн за цикл но та же офсетная ошибка

Answer (score 0):

разобрался спасибо всем! Офсет возникал из за то что в условии $i <= $count надо убрать равно. Теперь все ок